# Umbraco/Razor: Select where certain property ends with some string

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

In Razor, how do you select nodes where the NodeTypeAlias ends with Page?

This is a working example

```
var items = node.Children.Where("Visible").Where("NodeTypeAlias == \"TextPage\"");
```

but how do you do something like this

```
var items = node.Children.Where("Visible").Where(NodeTypeAlias.EndsWith("Page"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Hope it helps someone.

```
var items = node.Children.Where("Visible && NodeTypeAlias.EndsWith(\"Page\")");
```